# What kind of lichen is it?

Tags: species-identification, botany, mycology

I found that in a monastery garden in Czech Republic this winter. I tried to search it on the internet but unfortunately I didn't find it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it is a cup lichen from the genus [*Cladonia*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cladonia). A probable species is [*Cladonia pyxidata*](https://sv.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trattlav), which is relatively common across Europe. My lichen knowlegde is rusty though, and *Cladonia* is rather species rich with several species that are relatively similar.

[image]
(*C. pyxidata*, pic from http://fungi.myspecies.info/taxonomy/term/4557/media)

Comment: Cladonia is right for sure. Pyxidata I doubt. Impossible to be sure from a picture anyway.